# Unable to add values into my nested HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to access my key value pairs in my HashMap and if it matches the particular key, I will add items to its corresponding value which is a HashMap.

But it just doesn't work. Is there any issues in this code?

The "for-loop" works perfectly fine when non-nested HashMap is used.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

Map<String, Map<String,Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
map ==> {}

map.put("one", new HashMap<>())
$4 ==> null

map.put("two", new HashMap<>())
$5 ==> null

map.put("three", new HashMap<>())
$6 ==> null

for (Map.Entry e : map.entrySet()) {
    if (e.getKey().equals("two")) {
         e.getValue()).put("Tony", 123);
    }
}

Error:
cannot find symbol
   symbol: method put(java.lang.String,int)
  (e.getValue()).put("Tony", 123);
  ^_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _^
```

Comment: Just to note that the question has a missing left parenthesis in the for a loop before `e.getValue()`. Judging by the error you got, it's just a typo in the question, otherwise, it would give you a different error.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are declaring the loop control variable, `e`, is preventing the `e.getValue()` to return a recognizable value.

You need to parameterize `Map.Entry`:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Integer>> e : map.entrySet()) {
    if (e.getKey().equals("two")) {
        e.getValue().put("Tony", 123);
    }
}
```

From Java 10 onwards, you can also use `var`, which is a bit cleaner:

```
for (var e : map.entrySet()) {
    if (e.getKey().equals("two")) {
        e.getValue().put("Tony", 123);
    }
}
```